# Beacon sending notification while app in background

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, message, beacon

I wanted to push notification of beacon from Firebase to the user. If user came in the beacon range there should be a message like welcome to forward to the user, even in background. How can I do this?

Comment: There is huge amount of software functionality described in the question:  (a) beacon detection (b) sending a push notification with firebase (c) background operation.  I'd suggest you break down the question into a smaller scope that tackles one of these topics, and include with your question specifics of what you have tried.

Comment: I would suggest you orientate the reader.   For example:   In Firebase I want to ....  I would suggest you add your code and what you have tried.  Show that you have given some effort to solve the issue.